Fuzzy-join grouped data
I need to merge two data frames fuzzily on a Starttime_ms column. The data to be merged however have internal structure, i.e. groupings. They should be merged by the grouping variable File. How can this be done? Using fuzzyjoins function difference_left_join this does not seem possible: in row #13, the Quote "this is how" should not be assigned as the Files in df1 and df2 are different:
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(File) %>%
  # join:
  difference_left_join(x = .,
                       y = df2,
                       by = "Starttime_ms",
                       max_dist = 1500)
# A tibble: 20 × 6
# Groups:   File.x [5]
   File.x Utterance                                             Starttime_ms.x File.y Quote                Starttime_ms.y
   <chr>  <chr>                                                          <int> <chr>  <chr>                         <int>
 1 F01    "((34_m: x))"                                                1126730 NA     NA                               NA
 2 F01    "((68_m: in, points to r w: index @lorperi))"                2177901 NA     NA                               NA
 3 F12    "((130_m:@rct))"                                             2341143 NA     NA                               NA
 4 F12    "((175_m: r h closed palm down))"                            2457686 NA     NA                               NA
 5 F05    "((19_m: from ctct to rct)) "                                 905860 F05    is (name ID08.A)             905899
 6 F12    "((166_m: b h half closed palms down))"                      2414528 NA     NA                               NA
 7 F12    "((106_m:@lperi))"                                           2296469 NA     NA                               NA
 8 F06    "((100_m: r h open palm up @uprperi))"                       2511953 NA     NA                               NA
 9 F12    "((116_m:@rct))"                                             2309468 NA     NA                               NA
10 F12    "((21_m: l h closed palm up))"                                795914 NA     NA                               NA
11 F01    "((148_m:r hand moves sideways with 2 beats @rperi))"        2163502 NA     NA                               NA
12 F12    "((10_m: lf, points l then r w))"                             779882 NA     NA                               NA
13 F01    "((144_m:r rotate with palms))"                              2159122 F07    this is how                 2157727
14 F06    "((115_m:@uprperi))"                                         2642130 NA     NA                               NA
15 F01    "((185_m: l h close palm down))"                             2251525 NA     NA                               NA
16 F09    "((11_m: flaps h outwards @rct))"                            1436092 NA     NA                               NA
17 F01    "((81_m: r h ))"                                              220038 F01    the EXAM'S OPEN for…         220055
18 F01    "((32_m: projects hands forward @ct))"                        143758 NA     NA                               NA
19 F05    "((61_m: wipe from ctct to l + r periphery))"                2284146 NA     NA                               NA
20 F01    "((114_m:ard with palm upward))"                              808493 NA     NA                               NA

Any help with this is appreciated!
Data:
df2 <- structure(list(File = c("F01", "F01", "F05", "F09", "F17", "F07", 
                               "F17", "F01", "F01", "F05", "F16", "F05", "F12", "F07", "F01", 
                               "F06", "F17", "F16", "F16", "F07", "F05", "F05", "F12", "F01", 
                               "F07", "F17", "F08", "F01", "F17", "F07", "F08", "F17", "F16", 
                               "F17", "F01", "F12", "F01", "F16", "F08", "F09"), 
                      Quote = c("the EXAM'S OPEN for a:ll but",
                                                                 "yeah I watered them with beer", 
                                                                 "is (name ID08.A)", 
                                                                 ">do we wanna do this< or !not!", 
                                                                 "°this thing that I do really°", 
                                                                 "well we don't wanna do this anymore", 
                                                                 "!no! I came from a very homogenous place", 
                                                                 "I [need all of my !money!] to live", 
                                                                 "[okay ((name Mr)) look at this", 
                                                                 "°I'm not motivated that [enough?°]", 
                                                                 "we 're not going to (.)", 
                                                                 "↑ye:s of course you can go shopping", 
                                                                 "go in", 
                                                                 "this is how", 
                                                                 "NO:: LEAVE HER AL- ((v: grunts))", 
                                                                 "↓WHAT¿", 
                                                                 "↑you're not↑ from there°", 
                                                                 "I 'm I 'm just here to get my paycheck", 
                                                                 "Oh and I don't l(h)ike [i(h)t]", 
                                                                 "o:h !no!", 
                                                                 "let's !go!", "[just !think! about it]", 
                                                                 "°maybe you should just get on a plane and come home", 
                                                                 "ZEpark", 
                                                                 "!Ice!land", 
                                                                 "[let me in] the !fucking! [toilet] ", 
                                                                 "°↑oh↑ it's just another day in Philly.°", 
                                                                 "↑↑oh I [wanna] go play", 
                                                                 "°↑yeah my French isn't good↑° enough", "°f- o:h !shit!° ", 
                                                                 "<professionalization,> [that]", 
                                                                 "yo man", 
                                                                 "no I do need, <I will need to:> cut your ↑pay↑", 
                                                                 "like ↑how could it", 
                                                                 "bitch", 
                                                                 "you know your rank", 
                                                                 "a pack of cigarettes", 
                                                                 "shout out",
                                "rightio", "so WHAT?"), Starttime_ms = c(220055L,
                                                                                 2100242L, 905899L, 1402070L, 1994545L, 2429302L, 1764229L, 847000L, 
                                                                                 1601962L, 903107L, 1453737L, 1619669L, 2666162L, 2157727L, 257988L, 
                                                                                 461057L, 2229889L, 2636779L, 2305919L, 83699L, 908779L, 133598L, 
                                                                                 2038891L, 28300L, 783511L, 1287759L, 2268022L, 251412L, 1231539L, 
                                                                                 1451699L, 1297216L, 1189569L, 1308988L, 1134906L, 825516L, 2233996L, 
                                                                                 250552L, 2356355L, 1864314L, 222508L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))

df1 <- structure(list(File = c("F01", "F01", "F12", "F12", "F05", "F12", 
                               "F12", "F06", "F12", "F12", "F01", "F12", "F01", "F06", "F01", 
                               "F09", "F01", "F01", "F05", "F01"), Utterance = c("((34_m: x))", 
                                                                                 "((68_m: in, points to r w: index @lorperi))", 
                                                                                 "((130_m:@rct))", "((175_m: r h closed palm down))", 
                                                                                 "((19_m: from ctct to rct)) ", "((166_m: b h half closed palms down))", 
                                                                                 "((106_m:@lperi))", "((100_m: r h open palm up @uprperi))", 
                                                                                 "((116_m:@rct))", "((21_m: l h closed palm up))", 
                                                                                 "((148_m:r hand moves sideways with 2 beats @rperi))", 
                                                                                 "((10_m: lf, points l then r w))", 
                                                                                 "((144_m:r rotate with palms))", 
                                                                                 "((115_m:@uprperi))", "((185_m: l h close palm down))", 
                                                                                 "((11_m: flaps h outwards @rct))", "((81_m: r h ))", 
                                                                                 "((32_m: projects hands forward @ct))", 
                                                                                 "((61_m: wipe from ctct to l + r periphery))", 
                                                                                 "((114_m:ard with palm upward))"
                               ), Starttime_ms = c(1126730L, 2177901L, 2341143L, 2457686L, 905860L, 
                                                   2414528L, 2296469L, 2511953L, 2309468L, 795914L, 2163502L, 779882L, 
                                                   2159122L, 2642130L, 2251525L, 1436092L, 220038L, 143758L, 2284146L, 
                                                   808493L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                 "data.frame"))


do a post fuzzy join  dplyr::filter operation to exclude mismatches on your File criteria ?
